# Install older version of ghostscript on raspberry pi

Tags: ghostscript, apt

I think there is a problem with the version of Ghostscript and a printer I have installed on my Raspberry Pi Zero. The version of Ghostscript is **9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u3**.

How do I downgrade Ghostscript? Either that, or try the latest version of Ghostscript?

I typed **apt-cache policy** and got:

```
ghostscript:
  Installed: 9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u3
  Candidate: 9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u3
  Version table:
 *** 9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u3 500
        500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install ghostscript=9.26a~dfsg-0+deb9u6
```

But I got:

```
E: Version '9.26a~dfsg-0+deb9u6' for 'ghostscript' was not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to contact the package maintainer for Ghostscript on your OS (which appears to be Raspbian, which is basically Debian) or build Ghostscript from source yourself.

Debian appears to have 9.52 in testing.

The documentation on building Ghostscript from source can be found [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Make.htm)

Comment: Thanks KenS. Is there a way to add a relevant source repository to Raspbian? One that contains the previous/older version of Ghostscript?

Comment: Slightly puzzled. You add a source repository to your installation by (in our case) cloning it using Git. If you want to then use an older version of the source you would checkout the relevant tag. For example to get 9.25 you'd do "git checkout ghostpdl-9.25" and then build it. If you mean you want to add an older binary to the packages maintained by the Raspbian package manager, then that would be a question for hte package maintainer, its not a subject I know anything about I'm afraid. But I wouldn't recommend using anything earlier than 9.50 anyway for security reasons.